# How to sort data in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort data based on the number of keyword values, and if they are the same keyword values then I will sort them again based on the number of words.

Every index between `keyword` and `word` is related. Index 0 in `keyword` corresponds to index 0 in  `word`.

input:

```
keyword = {1,0,2,0,2}
word = {6,0,2,0,3}
```

output will be:

```
keyword = {2, 2, 1, 0, 0}
word = {3, 2, 6, 0, 0}
```

I tried to create a program like this but the output is not appropriate. How do I sort it correctly?

```
public static void sortAnswer(List<Integer> word, List<String> getDoc, List<Integer> keyOccurence){
    int[] totalWord = new int[word.size()] ;
    int[] mDoc = new int[word.size()];
    int[] totalKey = new int[word.size()];
    int g = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (int d = 0; d < word.size(); d++) {
        totalWord[k] = word.get(d);
        mDoc[k] = g;
        totalKey[k] = keyOccurence.get(d);
        k++;
        g++;
    }   

    int temp = 0;
    int t = 0;  
    int te = 0;      
    for(i = 0; i < word.size()-1; i ++)
    {
        for(int p=1; p<word.size(); p++)
        {
            if(totalKey[p-1] < totalKey[p])
            {
                temp = totalWord[p-1];
                t = mDoc[p-1];
                te = totalKey[p-1];

                totalWord[p-1] = totalWord[p];
                mDoc[p-1] = mDoc[p];
                totalKey[p-1] = totalKey[p];

                totalWord[p] = temp;
                mDoc[p] = t;
                totalKey[p] = te;
            }
        }
    }

    //Sorting the highest number of words
    g = 0;
    k = 0;
    i = 0;
    for (int d = 0; d < word.size(); d++) {
        totalWord[k] = word.get(d);
        mDoc[k] = g;
        totalKey[k] = keyOccurence.get(d);
        k++;
        g++;
    }   

    temp = 0;
    t = 0;  
    te = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < word.size()-1; i ++)
    {
        for(int p=1; p<word.size(); p++)
        {
            if (totalKey[p-1] == totalKey[p]) 
            {   
                if(totalWord[p-1] < totalWord[p]) {
                    temp = totalWord[p-1];
                    t = mDoc[p-1];
                    te = totalKey[p-1];

                    totalWord[p-1] = totalWord[p];
                    mDoc[p-1] = mDoc[p];
                    totalKey[p-1] = totalKey[p];

                    totalWord[p] = temp;
                    mDoc[p] = t;
                    totalKey[p] = te;
                }            
            }
        }
    }

    int f = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        f = mDoc[i];
        System.out.print("Total Key : "+totalKey[i]);
        System.out.println(" == Total Word : " +totalWord[i]);
        System.out.println("Document : " +getDoc.get(f));
        f++;
    }   

    System.out.println("\nValid Answer"); 
    f = mDoc[0];   
    String answer = getDoc.get(f);
    System.out.println(answer);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or putting print statements within your loops and finding where it goes wrong?

Comment: in line if (totalKey[p-1] == totalKey[p]), i just add else statement and program run it. there seems to be a mistake there

Comment: Why are you resetting the arrays between two sorts?

Comment: And you can easily achieve this in one sort by using `totalKey[p-1] < totalKey[p] || (totalKey[p-1] == totalKey[p] && totalWord[p-1] < totalWord[p])` as the condition for swapping.

Comment: oalah.. i just think that, bad logic ya. but your solution it work, thank you so much Dabiuteef :)